# Unity Editor does not fully render UI and is unresponsive on Windows 10

Tags: unity-game-engine

The editor window does not fully render and is unresponsive... I restored windows by completely reinstalling it, fresh install, all clean... and still same issue:
I checked Unity 2017.3, 2017.2 and 5.6, with DX9, 11 and 12... allways same issue.

I found 0 related issues on google, maybe I'm not using the correct wording for the search (Unresponsive Unity Editor Windows). On the Unity forums someone mentioned DX version being the issue, but I already forced all recent versions and it fails for all of them.

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and belongs on the Unity forum. By the way, try to install update for your graphics card. This may actually be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue is with Unity not being dpi aware so I had to remove my 150% scaling on my main 4K window in order for it to work.

Unity programmers my encounter this issue too, and come here for help as I did... I don't see why that's wrong @Programmer